# AWS CloudFormation - Import condition from other template

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible for template A to import a condition defined in template B?

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot import 'Conditions". The only thing you can import is the output variables (Exports using `"Export" : { "Name" : "Value"}` ) from another Cloudformation (CF) template using `Fn::ImportValue`.

If you can configure the CF template A to output a variable based on internal condition, CF template B could conditionally evaluate its value imported within, to differentiate its output.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the intrinsic function `Fn::ImportValue` in template A to import some values from another template B. In template B use the `"Export" : { "Name" : "Value"}` in the `Outputs` section to export that value. For more details see the aws docs

[AWS Cloudformation Import and Export Values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html)

Comment: That is not what I asked. I asked specifically about Importing/Exporting Conditions, not generic values.

Comment: @demonicdaron - yes, you asked about conditions, but still conditions will give a value, then why can't you export it ? you want me to write the entire CFT as example?